# how to handle exceptions in junit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, exception

I wrote some test cases to test some method. But some methods throw an exception. Am I doing it correctly?

```
private void testNumber(String word, int number) {
    try {
        assertEquals(word,  service.convert(number));
    } catch (OutOfRangeNumberException e) {
        Assert.fail("Test failed : " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Test
public final void testZero() {
    testNumber("zero", 0);
}
```

If I pass `-45`, it will fail with `OutOfRangeException` but I am not able to test specific exception like `@Test(Expected...)`

Answer (score 53):

An unexpected exception is a test failure, so you neither need nor want to catch one.

```
@Test
public void canConvertStringsToDecimals() {
    String str = "1.234";
    Assert.assertEquals(1.234, service.convert(str), 1.0e-4);
}
```

Until `service` does not throw an `IllegalArgumentException` because `str` has a decimal point in it, that will be a simple test failure.

An expected exception should be handled by the optional `expected` argument of `@Test`.

```
@Test(expected=NullPointerException.class)
public void cannotConvertNulls() {
    service.convert(null);
}
```

If the programmer was lazy and threw `Exception`, or if he had `service` return `0.0`, the test will fail.  Only an `NPE` will succeed.  Note that subclasses of the expected exception also work.  That's rare for `NPE`s, but common with `IOException`s and `SQLException`s.

In the rare case that you want to test for a specific exception message, you use the newish `ExpectedException` JUnit `@Rule`.

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException thrown= ExpectedException.none();
@Test
public void messageIncludesErrantTemperature() {
    thrown.expect(IllegalArgumentException.class);
    thrown.expectMessage("-400"); // Tests that the message contains -400.
    temperatureGauge.setTemperature(-400);
}
```

Now, unless the setTemperature throws an `IAE` and the message contains the temperature the user was trying to set, the test fails. This rule can be used in more sophisticated ways.

---

Your example can best be handled by:

```
private void testNumber(String word, int number)
        throws OutOfRangeNumberException {
    assertEquals(word,  service.convert(number));
}

@Test
public final void testZero()
        throws OutOfRangeNumberException {
    testNumber("zero", 0);
}
```

You can inline `testNumber`; now, it does not help much. You can turn this into a parametrized test class.

Answer (score 25):

Remove the try-catch block and add `throws Exception` to your test method, like:

```
@Test
public final void testZero() throws Exception {
    assertEquals("zero",  service.convert(0));
}
```

JUnit expects failing tests will throw Exceptions, your catching them is just stopping JUnit from being able to report them properly. Also this way the expected property on the @Test annotation will work.

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to catch the exception to fail the test. Just let it go (by declaring `throws`) and it will fail anyway.

Another case is when you actually expect the exception, then you put fail at the end of try block.

For example:

```
@Test
public void testInvalidNumber() {
  try {
      String dummy = service.convert(-1));
      Assert.fail("Fail! Method was expected to throw an exception because negative numbers are not supported.")
  } catch (OutOfRangeException e) {
      // expected
  }
}
```

You can use this kind of test to verify if your code is properly validating input and handles invalid input with a proper exception.

Comment: ExpectedException is the preferred way to test for expected exceptions.

Comment: You only need ExpectedException if you need to check the structure of the exception.  For example, CmisExceptions are supposed to have a specifc fault reason set inside them.  I've had to write tests to check that, and I used Hamcrest matchers for that purpose. If you just expect an exception, use the argument to @Test.

Answer (score 5):

There are several strategies that are open to you to deal with expected exceptions in your tests.  I think the JUnit annotations and try/catch idiom have already been mentioned above.  I'd like to draw attention to the Java 8 option of Lambda expressions.

For instance given:

```
class DummyService {
public void someMethod() {
    throw new RuntimeException("Runtime exception occurred");
}

public void someOtherMethod(boolean b) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Runtime exception occurred",
            new IllegalStateException("Illegal state"));
}
```

}

You can do this:

```
@Test
public void verifiesCauseType() {
    // lambda expression
    assertThrown(() -> new DummyService().someOtherMethod(true))
            // assertions
            .isInstanceOf(RuntimeException.class)
            .hasMessage("Runtime exception occurred")
            .hasCauseInstanceOf(IllegalStateException.class);
}
```

Take a look at this blog which covers most of the options with examples.

http://blog.codeleak.pl/2013/07/3-ways-of-handling-exceptions-in-junit.html

And this one explains the Java 8 Lambda option more fully:

http://blog.codeleak.pl/2014/07/junit-testing-exception-with-java-8-and-lambda-expressions.html