# Is it adviceable to throw an exception in Junit?

Tags: java, junit

I have been preaching to handle Exceptions and fail the test if any (example given below).But, is it really a right approach ? Anyway the Test Runner will carry the Execution. Why we need to do so ? Anticipating your thoughts.

Example: Assume A.a() throws Exception

```
@Test
public void exampleExceptionTest(){
try{
      A.a();
      //Assertion
   }
catch(Exception e){
 assert.fail();
 }
}
```

Should i rewrite the above into,

```
@Test
public void exampleExceptionTest()throws Exception{
 A.a();
 //Assertion
 }
```

Comment: dupplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596418/how-to-handle-exceptions-in-junit

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to catch an exception in a unit test just so you can perform an explicit `fail()`. The test will fail if an unexpected exception is encountered, so the best practice is to do as in your second code snippet:

```
@Test
public void exampleExceptionTest() throws Exception {
    A.a();
    //Assertion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `expected` parameter of `@Test` annotation

i.e

```
@Test(expected=SomeException.class)
public void exampleExceptionTest() {
    A.a();
    //Assertion
}
```